# trouble getting input via CMD - java

Tags: java

As the title stated, I cannot get any input from anyone. It should echo the error of InputTypeMismatch or if you do numbers, then It will say nullreference error.

Can someone correct this? This is driving me insane. I don't know where to check.

Thanks is advance :)

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
            at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
            at TestFile.promptsentence(TestFile.java:54)
            at TestFile.main(TestFile.java:43)
```

Here is a example:

```
    public class TestFile(){

            Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

            public static main(String[] args){
                    long inp = inp.NextLong();
                    // prompts
                    String input = Long.valueOf(inp);

                    System.out.println(input);

            }


    }
```

Comment: Put it outside the main method. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: above main method or below if I am calling things from the main method/would ever call them from the main method.

Comment: @Drogba, he can put it in the main method its ok.

Comment: I took it out and since I had f referenced inside the main method it errored me saying f was not static.

Comment: First off, your public static main does not declare a type.  It should be "public static void main"

Comment: Please post enough code (that will actually compile) to reproduce your problem.  How `checksent` method is defined  and where is it located?

Comment: Ahh, I did decalir void with that.

Comment: @JobanDhillon He's calling "f.checksent(1)" in repeat method. Why do u think he can declare a local variable in main method and be accessible in another mehtod?

Comment: I am calling promptsentence(1) from the main.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full error message.

Comment: By editing your question to say "_this has been fixed_" you obliterate all of the context that makes the answers and comments meaningful.  Please do not do this.  It would be better to just delete the question (which you can't do because there are answers).  I'm going to rollback your edit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
/* Here among class variables, outside any methods:*/

    Private TestFile f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        f = new TestFile();
        f.promptsentence();

    };
```

Hopefully, it's clear enough.

I'm not making any statements about the rest of the code - just answering the question about object `f` declaration and assignment.

Comment: I like what you did here. I done something like this and resolved it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`TestFile f` is not within the scope of `public void repart()`. Put it outside of main by doing something like

```
public class TestFile {

    private TestFile f = new TestFile();

    public static main(String[] args){
        // Some Code
    }

    public void repart() {
        if(f.checksent(1) == true){
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

It *should* work now. Overall I don't think this is a great way of doing it. If i were doing this assignment (i'm assuming its an assignment) I would Make 2 class Files. One `Main`, and One `TestFile` and then do this.

```
// TestFile.java
public class TestFile {

    public TestFile() {
        // some constructor stuff
    }

    public void repart() {
        if(f.checksent(1) == true){
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// Main.java
public class Main{

    private TestFile f = new TestFile();

    private static TestFile f = new TestFile();

    public static main(String[] args){
        f.repart();
    }

}
```

This imo is the better way to do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I still get the error that f is not static

Comment: @pattmorter - 
**Wrong**. `Private TestFile f`; should be a class variable that is initiated as `f=newTESTfile();` in `main()`, assuming that main will then call all other methods.

Comment: @user2262111 then change `private TestFile f` to `private static TestFile f`. And @PM77-1, **ok**.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be helpful for you to start here [Java Class and Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

The errors you have are compile time errors

- main() function syntax is wrong. It should be like `public static void main(String[] args)`
- you don't have the "checksent()" method defined and you are trying to access it.

Comment: No. Thanks for the link i will check it.